# Angular code persists when backend down

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, web-sql

**A hypothetical question**

I am working on a Rails API backend / Angular.js frontend, served through the Rails asset pipeline.

I have noticed something interesting during my development: if I bring down the Rails server, the page that is displaying still functions to some level, executing javascript.

Can code be written in the front-end in this scenario and be relied upon to execute without being served any code from the asset pipeline (assuming all the code has been downloaded to the page)?

For example:

- Try to connect to another (outage) server and advise the backend is down
- Display a more interactive 404 message than a static page
- Allow the user to keep editing and save their work in the browser, then upload to the server when it is available.
- Cache the application data in an IndexedDB / WebSQL and allow full functionality in offline mode

Comment: localstorage is dedicated to this, but depends on browsers

Comment: If you have one concatenated big file and all the templates cached, then even cross-browser all should be loaded correctly - apart from possibly images - if there are no new requests triggered.

Comment: I mean can you rely on purpose-written code to function offline.. can you trap a 404 for example and keep working

Comment: Yes, as long as you have successfully loaded all your javascript (either from the server or from cache), your browser will work quite happily if you correctly handle Ajax errors and don't otherwise leave the page.